# Banner Ad is too wide for my Corona app

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

I'm using the Corona SDK to create an application. I have implemented advertisements but banner ad is too wide for my device.

I'm not sure what's wrong. I have some suspicions.

I believe that it may be the fact that I am using "zoomEven"

If it is the fact that I am using "zoomEven", is there any way I can resize the ad?

Comment: Could You please show some code related to mentioned advertisement and `zoomEvent`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using zoomEvent?

Comment: @RobMiracle Yes, so the game will fit the screen properly.

Comment: There are other techniques beside zoomEven to make your app fit the screen.  If having the ads fit is important, then perhaps you should investigate other ways to make the screen fit.